# Dynamically manipulate php cookies with javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm currently building a dynamic menu bar(vertical and horizontal). in the default position its vertical. the user have the option to show the horizontal position and hide and vertical. I am currently doing that with javascript/ jquery. in order to keep the menu bar in the horizontal position i am keeping a count with a cookie. the problem is that when i use the click function in javascript i want to change the value of the cookie. i have no knowledge of how to do this. Can anyone assist me with this. all help would be appreciated.

```
 <?php
setcookie('menu', 1, time()+(86400));
 ?>
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#temp').hide();
            if(<?php echo $_COOKIE['menu'];?> == 1){
                $('#topmenu').hide();
                $('#sidemenu').floating().dropShadow().floating();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').hide();
            }else{
                $('#topmenu').show();
                $('#topmenu').dropShadow();
                $('#sidemenu').hide();
                $('#sidemenu').removeShadow();
            }   

            $('#move').click(function(){

                $('#sidemenu').hide("drop",{},2000);
                $('#sidemenu').removeShadow();                  
                $('#topmenu').show();
                $('#topmenu').dropShadow();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').show();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').floating().dropShadow().floating();
            });

        });
```

This is what i have so far and the default cookie is working as well as the javascript. its just to change the cookie value now.

thanks.

This is what I have done since so far;

```
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d){
            var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );  
            if ( exp_y ){
                var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
                cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
            }
            document.cookie = cookie_string;
        }
var x = document.cookie;
            if(x == "menu=1"){
                $('#topmenu').show();
                $('#topmenu').dropShadow();             
            }else{
                $('#topmenu').hide();
                $('#sidemenu').floating().dropShadow().floating();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').hide();           
            }   

            $('#move').click(function(){
                set_cookie ( "menu", "1", 2012, 01, 15 );
                $('#sidemenu').hide("drop",{},2000);
                $('#sidemenu').removeShadow();                  
                $('#topmenu').show();
                $('#topmenu').dropShadow();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').show();
                $('#sidemenu_bottom').floating().dropShadow().floating();
            });
```

I'm however still having problems. Its not doing what i want it to do.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

forget about php. Check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

In JS (jQuery) you can do this.. so don't mess up your code with PHP tags in JS

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
alert( $.cookie("example") );
```